# Call to a member function findOneByName() on null when getting repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a method that sends statistics to a group of people.

```
public function sendNewsletterStatistics ()
{
    $snapshotName = $this->getSnapshotName($this->period);

    $snapshotRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(NewslettersStatisticSnapshot::class);
    $snapshot = $snapshotRepo->findOneByName($snapshotName);

...
```

My problem is that when I run the method, I get this output:

> Error: Call to a member function findOneByName() on null 
>   /usr/src/app/src/AppBundle/Service/NewsletterStatisticsService.php:53

I have verified that my `NewslettersStatisticSnapshot` class exists, and I have checked that I have the correct `use` statement needed to import this class.

What am I doing wrong here?

===

Edit: Here is what is at the top of my entity.

```
/**
 * NewslettersStatisticSnapshot
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="newsletters_statistics_snapshot")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\NewslettersStatisticSnapshotRepository")
 */
class NewslettersStatisticSnapshot
{
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->entityManager your variable entityManager is not defined.

You can : 
public function sendNewsletterStatistics (EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)

$this->entityManager => $entityManager